# Printing a string and executing functions inside a class [Python]

Tags: python, function, class

For my school assignment we have to write a program to simmulate a traffic light. I've got the program working the only problem is that the code is a bit of a mess because I don't know how to use classes properly. And the documentation just confuses me (a bit of a noob).

So I just copied the function I wanted to change an variable in multiple times and changed the variables by hand. I know it's possible to do this with classes and just make an instance of this class with the right variable but I can seem to get it to work. Here is a small example in "**pseudo code**" of what I want to achieve.

This code is a timer that times for how long the traffic light is on. I want to make a class that can accept a side (`left`,`right`,`front`,`back`) and print this string so I dont have to copy the code and manualy enter the side. But I can just make an instance with one of the sides.

```
import time

class trafficlight_timer:
    def __init__(self, side1):
        self.side = side1

    def trafficlight(self, side1):
        s = 0
        b = 5
        t_max = 10
        print self.side,  "is green"
        if b > t_max:
            b = t_max
        while s <= 60:
            time.sleep(1)
            s += 1
            if s == b:
                print self.side, "is red"
                print self.side, "was green for %d seconds." % s
                print ""
                s = 65
    trafficlight()

instance_left = trafficlight_timer('left')
```

If someone could point out to me how this should be done I would be very grateful. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with what you have? I didn't try to run it, but it looks mostly fine to me, except that you wouldn't normally call `trafficlight()` from inside the class body (may not even be legal syntax, I'm not sure).

```
import time

class trafficlight_timer:
    def __init__(self, side1):
        self.side = side1

    def trafficlight(self):
        s = 0
        b = 5
        t_max = 10
        print self.side,  "is green"
        if b > t_max:
            b = t_max
        while s <= 60:
            time.sleep(1)
            s += 1
            if s == b:
                print self.side, "is red"
                print self.side, "was green for %d seconds." % s
                print ""
                s = 65

instance_left = trafficlight_timer('left')
instance_left.trafficlight()
```

The only changes I made were to delete `trafficlight()` from the class body, remove the redundant and unused `side1` parameter from the `trafficlight` function, and call `trafficlight()` on the `instance_left` instance. The output looks like this:

```
left is green
left is red
left was green for 5 seconds.
```

If that's not what you want, describe in more detail what you expect for the output and what undesirable output you are getting.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I wanted! Kindof derpy of me to forget how to execute it properly.